# New with Wordpress CMS and databases

Tags: database, html, wordpress, css, content-management-system

Can anyone help me, i need to make a multi lingual website with news, events and gallery section to be updatable via Wordpress. I have never worked with Wordpess before, my website is complete and it is uploaded to a server, i have installed Wordpress on the server but i don't know what to do next. I know i am supposed to make a database but i don't know how, some servers have access to a menu where you can easily create a database, but i don't have such access. So what i am asking for i if someone can help me make a database and help me make a CMS for the updatable sections of the site. I am new to this, i have been working with websites before, redesigned them with HTML5 and CSS3 but i am a total noob about databases and CMS using Wordpress. :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the plugin called **WPML**.

It is a premium plugin but it would make your Multilingual site easy to setup and manage. Basically you will add what languages you want as your secondary, tertiary and soon.

Comment: I don't want a plugin, i just need a simple CMS to put stuff in the news, events and gallery section. the website is complete and it has 3 languages and icons to switch between them. I have built it in Dreamweaver and uploaded it. It is functional and the only thing it needs now is a CMS and a database to be updatable with news, but i have no experience with databases and CMS. I need someone who is willing to help me to do this step by step, because Youtube and other tutorials are not that helpful.

Comment: Hi Marko,

You said you wanted a Multi-lingual site and I suggested to use WPML because it is one if not the only 'best' plugin for handling multi-lingual content.

Basically, what it will do is with your current Wordpress setup it will create an option for people to choose what language they wanted for the site that is base on your WPML setup,  for more info visit their official [site](https://wpml.org/features/).
If you don't like my suggestion, the only way for you is to create addition installation of Wordpress per language.
For you issue with access to Database, contact your hosting comp.